# Is there a way to convert a specific tweet given its direct URL to JSON format?

Tags: python, twitter

I used a scraper ([Jefferson Henrique's Script](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python)) to download old tweets dating from a few months to 2 years ago using a keyword. I got the following details: username, date, retweets, favorites, text, geo, mentions, hashtags, id, and permalink. Now I need to perform a location check so I can delete tweets which are not from the same country of my choice. In order to do that, my algorithm needs the tweets to be in JSON format. Is there a way to convert a specific tweet given its direct URL (or other details) to JSON format?

Below is an image of the available data saved in a .tsv file and I need to make its JSON format. And I'm working on more than 10,000 tweets per run. [Available Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhkN9.png)

Comment: Can you show some data samples?

Comment: I've edited the post to include available data samples. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some text data?

Comment: Try to use pandas library. https://pandas.pydata.org/